# How to create variations in commerce file?

Tags: commerce

I am creating a ecommerce site selling downloads. Currently, I am trying to get product attributes to work with commerce file. I have created a select list taxonomy for operating systems, so the user uploading the file would be able to select operation systems. I need a way for users to be able to upload different files depending on operating systems they selected, for the same product. Thanks in advance! (I am using a normal Drupal with commerce installed I.e. Not kickstart 2, just a standard Drupal installation)

Answer (score 0):

The set up should be:  a single product display whose product reference field has both the (I'm assuming) Windows file and Mac file.  The relevant product attribute being that taxonomy term.  So, in your product type, place that taxonomy term.  It sounds as if you put that taxonomy term on your product display, which is a node type.
Note:  products entities = variations in Kickstart 2.  Products I believe refer to product displays.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am using not kickstart, just normal Drupal.